# Formatting the thesis chapter title

Tags: formatting, chapters, thesis

I am presently working on my masters thesis. My code is as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{thesis}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    %My introduction
\end{document}
```

But I am getting the output as follows:

[image]

I need the page to look like as follows:

[image]

What shall I do?

Comment: Sectional units and their representation is heavily dependent on packages, or in this case, your document class `Thesis.cls`. If you wish to receive help, we need to have access to that file (directly, or via a link).

Comment: Also, probably there are conditions on the margins to be met. Those would be helpful as well on top of what @Werner said

Comment: @Werner please see the thesis.cls http://pastebin.com/meBL7mXh

Comment: Is this thesis.cls provided by your institution? Is the format you "need" required by the institution? If the answer to both is 'yes', you should complain to the institution. If the answer to the first is 'no', and you are borrowing someone's `thesis.cls`, then discard it and start with `report.cls`. If the answer first is 'yes' and to the second is 'no', then there is no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks very much like the regular chapter head. Here's the default [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) header(s):

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{% Header for \chapter
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{% Header for \chapter*
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

I've taken the above, and added font-changing macros (`\chaptertitlefont` and `\chapternamefont`) where needed so you can modify them to suit your needs.

Here's a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}
\newcommand{\chapternamefont}{\scshape\Large}% Chapter name font
\newcommand{\chaptertitlefont}{\LARGE\bfseries}% Chapter title font
\def\@makechapterhead#1{% Header for \chapter
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        {\chapternamefont\@chapapp\space \thechapter\par\nobreak}% \huge\bfseries
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    {\chaptertitlefont #1\par\nobreak}
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{% Header for \chapter*
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    {\chaptertitlefont#1\par\nobreak}
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
%My introduction
\end{document}
```

`\chapternamefont` sets the font for *Chapter 1* (`\scshape\Large` by default) and `\chaptertitlefont` sets the font for **Introduction** (`\LARGE\bfseries` by default).